# Can't catch System.Xaml.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, xml-parsing

I have an empty string, when I use it on an XmlReader it gives of course a parsing "root element is missin" exception, am trying to catch it but the `try,catch` doesn't respond, is there a way to catch this exception or detect that my string is not parsable.

```
System.IO.StringReader stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader("");

System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Create(stringReader, new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings());

try
{
    object ob = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);//
    mycv = (Canvas)ob;
}
    catch (Exception ex) //even if I use System.Xaml.XamlParseException
{
    mycv = new Canvas();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the `try,catch` doesn't respond"? I just ran your exact code, and it caught the exception just fine. (Though of course you'd be better off catching the specific exception you expect.)

Comment: I think I got to clean my project, I'll give it a try

Comment: still not working, is there a way to detect whether a root element exist, @RV1987

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object ob = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Here you are using Windows markup XamlReader, so `System.Xaml.XamlParseException` won't get thrown here instead you should catch `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`.

This should work for you -

```
try
{
    object ob = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);//
    mycv = (Canvas)ob;
}
    catch (System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException ex)
{
    mycv = new Canvas();
}
```